# stuck drawstrings

Tags: clothing

so i have this drawstring sweater, and i kinda tied the strings together and now they wont come undone. they also have little knots at the end, making it almost impossible to untie the knot. this is also my favorite sweater, and i really dont want to cut the strings. im also too embarassed to ask anyone in person. so now im stuck in this sweater and i have school tomorrow, and im freaking out. SOMEBODY HELP ME

Comment: [Possibly useful?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/how-to-undo-a-stubborn-knot-without-using-fingers)

Answer (score 2):

use some hairpin (or something similar , metal, thin, no sharp tip) and try different parts of the knot to see where is easier to loosen. work little by little and in parallel on the whole knot and trace the string paths visually. keep calm and work patiently once it's loose enough for the end knots to pass through, the rest is easy.

Comment: A hairpin is a good idea. I also use tweezers, and/or needle-nose pliers, and/or regular pliers.